# Cross Tab and Chi Square Test in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python.

I have a table, with a persons preference (A or B

```
    Preference
0      A
1      A
2      B
3      A
4      B
```

I wanted to make a cross tab table and then perform a Chi squared test

So the cross tab table is

```
A   number of A's
B   number of B's
```

and then a chi square test giving the pvalue and degrees of freedom

I know how to do this in R

```
tbl= xtabs( ~ Preference, data=df)
chisq.test(tbl)
```

But can't figure out how to do it in python, though it seems fairly basic.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing crosstab

you may use `pd.crosstab(df.index,df.preferences)`

for chi square test use scipy module as support

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

stat, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(df)
```